# What is causing connection reset in my tcp server?

Tags: java, tcp, runtime, netty, socketexception

This error can happen at anytime but the error message is not showing where it happens during runtime,

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRlCH.png)

TCPServerhandler with the closing part

[TCPServerHandler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7N5y.png)

TCPserverRun code

[TCPServer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khKFO.png)

Comment: Is this question removed?

Answer (score 0):

A connection reset occurs if the server tries to read or write data after the connection was closed by the client.